# Merging Observable and take action when all subjects have emitted a value

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, subject

I'd like to merge observables into one and then subscribe when ALL of the subjects have emitted a value. So far, I've tried Observable.merge and Observable.zip

```
public A:Subject<any> = new Subject();
public B:Subject<any> = new Subject();
public C:Subject<any> = new Subject();
public D:Subject<any> = new Subject();
public Complete:Subject<any> = new Subject();

A.next(true);
B.next(true);
C.next(true);
D.next(true);

Observable.zip(A,B,C,D).subscribe(res=>{Complete.next(true)})
```

But if I do above, I think the subscriber will listen to any of A,B,C or D subject to emit a value, not ALL.
What would be the way to wait until A,B,C and D have all emitted a value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable.forkJoin` that waits until all source Observables emit at least one value and all of them complete. But since you're using Subjects it's very likely that they don't complete so using `.zip()` makes sense.

The `zip()` operator emits `X`th only when all source emitted `X` values. In your case `zip()` will emit a single item only when all `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` emit at least one item.

However, if you use `merge` it'll emit every time any of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` emit an item.

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/hihutoj/8/edit?js,output

Comment: Could you provide me with a plunkr if possible? because when I try that exact code in my code, zip operator doesn't emit anything....

Comment: Of course you first need to subscribe and then call `next()`s :)

Comment: Ugh, this is driving me nuts. I dont know why this same code wouldn't work on my Angular2 project... I just have that exact same thing in my services and I call the service, but zip doesn't emit anything :(